# I can´t put a webview in FULL SCREEN

Tags: android, webview, fullscreen

**Hi, i have this problem and i am newbie with this..**

[This is the image of my problem](http://imageshack.com/a/img191/6905/oizp.png)

**As you can see, i get a margin that i DONT WANT!
All that i did , was put the Webview and extended it all that i could.
But i get a margin.
But in MARGIN option, it dont have margin, WTF!**

[This is the imagen that i want](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-_xch89VynUE/UI0Ozpgx4OI/AAAAAAAAA3Q/e_0Mbz9CXng/s1600/android_webview.png)

**Here my code ( BUT, i think that this doesn´t have relation with the webview size D:  )**

```
     public class SecondActivity extends Activity
     {
    private WebView browser;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);



    browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

            //habilitamos javascript y el zoom
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

            //ZOOM
    browser.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);

            browser.loadUrl("http://lolking.net");

    browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        // evita que los enlaces se abran fuera nuestra app en el navegador de android
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            return false;
        }   

    });

    // setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);



   }   

}
```

**And.. Here my layout:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/fondo"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".SecondActivity" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="0dp" />
```

Thanks and sorry for my english..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the padding from your RelativeLayout.

You have defined:

```
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Comment: Really thanks for responding and helping me, but, I have a new problem :| in layout the problem is solved, but when I open the app I see the margin, why this happend? I saved, idk what could be, really :|